# Efficient reorder and serve data

Tags: php, html, caching, performance

I want build a lightweight cached system (few server-resources) for easy serve pages (without SQL queries, without heavy-functions...), but end result depends of multiple user profiles.

[image]

I know existence of APC, memcached and other third-systems... The purpose of this question is learn the most efficient way (and theorical explanations) in a specific coding-scene.

What method I should use? (more efficient in end-process)

A) Multiple and different static html file-part readings (show in image, I think that bad performance for several read access to hard disk)

B) A single-file reading (dynamic script), that include data needed and reorder self (with strpos, str_replace ...)

C) Other better solution

Very thanks,
Note: Sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT:** Suppose I have applied APC and memcached on my system. I'm interested in system scheme/coding/structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using memcached or APC is going to be a lot better than using static files. Generally speaking, you should use memcached if you have a bunch of web servers all serving content and want the cache to be shared between all web nodes, and use APC if you have just one or don't need a shared cache. These are the fast because they store your data in memory, and memory access is several orders of magnitude better that disk ready. That said, using static files as a cache is going to be a lot better than not using any kind of caching at all.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can use APC or memcached (and I will use), but still I'll have to use a dynamic/static struct in disk... I need to know the best way in this area.